# No puedo ejecutar mis migraciones a phpmyadmin con Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando de ejecutar las migraciones y al momento de ejecutar el comando *php artisan migrate*, me arroja esto: (He modificado el error ya que ahora me arroja este.)

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'colegio'
>
> migrate [--bench [BENCH]] [--database [DATABASE]] [--force] [--path [PATH]] [--package [PACKAGE]] [--pretend] [--seed]

No entiendo qué debo hacer, ya he configurado estas rutas `__"app/config/local/database.php"__ *, *__"app/config/database.php"__`
pero no entiendo este error.

Este es mi codigo del archivo .env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=colegio
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: en tu archivo `.env` ya configuraste bien tus credenciales; es decir el usuario y contraseña? por que las comillas vacías en `''@localhost` me indica que no lo has hecho

Comment: no tenía ese archivo, entonces lo creé, pero el nombre debería ser .env?

Comment: ese archivo esta dentro de la raíz de tu proyecto; es decir su tu proyecto se llama lina entonces debes buscar directo dentro de la carpeta lina y ahi debe aparecer

Comment: Sí, ya lo tengo, sólo debo configurar ese archivo, cierto?

Comment: si ahi tienes que poner tus credenciales de acceso, si te sigue dando problemas dale a actualziar a tu pregunta y añade el código que ahi viene para ayudarte

Comment: me siguió dando el mismo error entonces edité la pregunta,

Comment: en ciertas configuraciones tendrás que cambiar `DB_HOST=localhost` por `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

Comment: No conozco migraciones a phpmyadmin en Laravel, ¿tal vez se refiere a MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hay dos cuestiones que le pueden estar dando problemas:

1. El Usuario con el cual realiza la conexión no tiene todos los permisos, sería bueno probar dando todos los grants posibles.
2. Puede que la conexión esté mal hecha, pruebe haciendo una pequeña prueba de un echo para saber si la conexión de fijo le está funcionando a la base.

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta el comando:
   `php artisan config:cache`

Algunas veces, cuando modificamos nuestro archivo .env, Laravel no lo actualiza en nuestro cache. Tu error muestra que no se especificó ningún usuario para tu Base de Datos aún cuando lo bien especificado.

El comando `php artisan config:cache` limpia la cache y configura una nueva.

Comment: He ejecutado ese comando pero todavía no resuelvo el problema, pero para próximos problemas tendré en cuenta el comando que indicaste, lo encuentro muy útil.

Comment: Sin querer ofenderte, **¿Haz iniciado tu servicio de MySQL?**, por ejemplo si usas `XAMPP`, debes iniciar el servicio y te mostrará un id de proceso (PID) y un puerto de acceso.

Acabo de probar en mi Pc y si desactivo el servicio me marca exactamente el mismo error que a ti.

Comment: claro, siempre inicio los servicios, por si algo lo acabé de intentar con y sin los servicios pero me sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: Intenta añadiendo esta línea de código antes de `DB_HOST=localhost`:

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql`

Comment: listo, ya lo probé pero sigue con el mismo problema

Comment: Ahora prueba cambiando localhost por 127.0.0.1

Comment: muchas gracias por la colaboración, ya lo solucioné, era un error muy grave en este archivo ->  *__"app/config/database.php"__*  el grandísimo error era que le faltaba una o a root